# ASP.NET: Am I safe from SQL Injection and XSS in this situation?

Tags: asp.net, xss, sql-injection

I've a blog-driven ASP.NET website. 
Under the post, there is a Comment block to let readers post comments.

I've used some TextBoxes and TextArea for that.

To Prevent XSS:

I've filtered the input by using: Server.HtmlEncode() Method (I don't care about text formatting).

To Prevent SQL-Injection:

I'm using Linq To SQL (that should be like parametrized queries I think!).

Am I Safe now?

cuz I've set ValidateRequest="false" in the page directive.

Here is the code:

```
ArticlesDataClasses dc = new ArticlesDataClasses();

        ArticleComment newComm = new ArticleComment()
        {
            ArticleID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ArticleID"]),
            CommentAuthor = Server.HtmlEncode(txtName.Text),
            CommentText = Server.HtmlEncode(txtComment.InnerHtml).Replace("\n", "<br />"),
            CommentAuthorEmail = Server.HtmlEncode(txtMail.Text),
            CommentTime = DateTime.Now,
            Enabled = false
        };

        dc.ArticleComments.InsertOnSubmit(newComm);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Thanks..

Comment: it *sounds* like your safe, but can you show the code to persist the comment to the database? that is the most important part. (for SQL injection prevention)

Comment: Thanks, RPM1984, I've edited the post and placed the code.

Comment: yep, your safe. a hint though, you should do your last-minute encoding somewhere else (not in the code for the insert). for one, `int.Parse` will throw an exception if the `ArticleID` QS is not an INT. Should use TryParse there, and yes, sanitize the input prior to doing your save. But overall, you look OK.

Comment: Looks good. OWASP provides a great and open source web application library called ESAPI, http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API. Also Security Compass offers a XSS Me and SQL Inject  plugins for FF.

Comment: Thanks RPM1984 for advices, but where is the best place to do encoding?

Comment: gnome, I thank you for the link.

Comment: Instead of Server.HtmlEncode use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode - http://www.aspnetsource.com/blog/post-server-htmlencode-vs.aspx - or even use AntiXss - http://wpl.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters and encoding are the major ones, but you also may want to take into cross-site request attack, and prevent posting if the referrer isn't your site:

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/02/anatomy-of-csrf-attack.aspx